# Plotly, plotting polygons and multipolygons and the background

Tags: python, json, plotly, maps, choropleth

I'm trying to plot data on maps, and thus far I'm using geopandas and plotly. I can get the data to parse and merge, but I run into a problem when the data is plotted. For some reason, some shapes will color over the entire background instead of inside their shapes. It's about a third of the data, for some reason.

[Data Rendering Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMCEj.png)

[Data Rendering Improperly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o8Z3.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj

# reading in the shapefile
map_df = gpd.read_file("mn-cd6-precincts.json")
map_df.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), inplace=True)

# Load the voter data
df = pd.read_csv("voting_by_precinct.csv")

# Set the two columns to be something that can be merged
map_df["PrecinctID"] = map_df["PrecinctID"].astype(str)
df["PrecinctID"] = df["PrecinctID"].astype(str)

# Merge the data
merged = pd.merge(map_df, df, how='left', on='PrecinctID')

# define the map
fig = px.choropleth(merged,
                    geojson=merged.geometry,
                    locations=merged.index,
                    color="PrecinctID")

# Sets the current location which is viewed on startup
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=1)

fig.show()
```

I looked briefly into the data that's rendering improperly, and they're almost all multipolygons. I'm not fully certain what this means, but there are multipolygons which render properly as well.

Update:

[Location Data](https://pastebin.com/h78tj67f)

[Count Data](https://pastebin.com/VTxhXYVr)

Comment: Please add a small example of input data to the question.

Comment: @MariaKozlova Added location and count data